# Oracle Compare two values in a row

Tags: select, compare, where-clause, rows, oracle12c

I have a table like below

```
value  id

yes    1
NO     2
ABC    3
ABC    4
```

I wanted to compare the values of id 3 and 4 and if the values are same then it needs to return the value of id 1 else it should return the value of id d.

In this case since value of id 3 "ABC" and 4 "ABC" are same and hence it should return "yes".

so how to compare the values of same row and return the value accordingly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Straightforward (sample data in lines #1 - 6; query begins at line #7):

```
SQL> with test (value, id) as
  2    (select 'yes', 1 from dual union all
  3     select 'NO' , 2 from dual union all
  4     select 'ABC', 3 from dual union all
  5     select 'ABC', 4 from dual
  6    )
  7  select case when (select value from test where id = 3) =
  8                   (select value from test where id = 4)
  9              then (select value from test where id = 1)
 10              else (select value from test where id = 2)
 11         end result
 12  from dual;

RESULT
----------
yes

SQL>
```